# Testing $scope in AngularJs controller with dependency on $filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I've gone through a few tutorials and basic examples but I'm having a hard time writing unit tests for my controller. I've seen code snippets instantiating controllers and letting angular inject the `$rootScope` object which in turn is used to create a new `scope` object for the controller. But I can't figure out why `ctrl.$scope`? **is undefined**:

```
 describe('EmployeeCtrl', function () {
    var scope, ctrl, $httpBackend;

    beforeEach(inject(function (_$httpBackend_, $rootScope, $controller, $filter) {
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;       

        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        ctrl = $controller('EmployeeCtrl', { $scope: scope});
        expect(ctrl).not.toBeUndefined();
        expect(scope).not.toBeUndefined();   //<-- PASS!      
        expect(ctrl.$scope).not.toBeUndefined();  //<-- FAIL!       
    }));
});
```

I ended up using the `scope` variable instead of `ctrl.$scope` but then on my first test I couldn't figure out how to unit test a **function variable** inside my controller:

**Controller:**

```
 function EmployeeCtrl($scope, $http, $filter, Employee) {
  var searchMatch = function (haystack, needle) {
   return false;
  }
 }
```

**Broken unit test:**

```
it('should search ', function () {                
    expect(ctrl.searchMatch('numbers','one')).toBe(false);
});
```

This is what I get

> TypeError: Object # has no method 'searchMatch'

How do you test that function? As a workaround I moved my method to $scope so I could test for `scope.searchMatch` but I was wondering if this is the only way.

Finally, on my tests is appears `$filter` **is undefined too**, how do you inject it? I tried this but didn't work:

```
ctrl = $controller('EmployeeCtrl', { $scope: scope, $filter: $filter });
```

Thanks

**Update:**
The method mentioned above to inject $filter works just fine.

Comment: my jasmine test breaks on the inject method. It is not found. What am I missing. angular is not null. I have a test that passes that verifies it's loaded.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

My understanding is that, in Angularjs, you pass a scope object to the controller when the application is starting and the controller modify the scope. The controller is not called anymore.

What a controller is really doing, in Angularjs, is initializing the scope: the controller only runs one time.
If you understand this, you realize that asking to the controller for the scope like this:

```
currentScope = myController.scope;
```

doesn't makes sense.

(Incidentally, one of the things I don't like in Angular is the names that they have choosen. If what a 'controller' is doing is initializing the scope then it's not really a controller. There are a lot of this in the Angular API).

I think that the 'proper' way for testing a 'controller' is creating a new blank scope from scratch in a Jasmine *beforeEach* clause and using the 'controller' for **initializing** a new blank scope like this::

```
var ctrl, myScope;

beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope) {
    myScope = $rootScope.$new();
    ctrl = $controller('myController', {
        $scope: myScope
    });
}));
```

And then testing the new created scope has the expected properties:

```
it('In the scope, the initial value for a=2', function() {
            expect(myScope.a).toBe(2);
});
```

In other words, you don’t test the controller; you test the scope that the controller has created.

So, you're doing it right.

Comment: That makes more sense. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 3):

Here is another pattern that might be simpler to follow:

```
var $scope;
beforeEach(module(function ($provide) {
  $scope = {
    // set anything you want here or nothing
  };
  $provide.value('$scope', $scope);
}));

var ctrl;
beforeEach(inject(function ($controller) {
  ctrl = $controller('MyController');
}));

it('should test something...', function () {
  // $scope will have any properties set by
  // the controller so you can now do asserts
  // on them.
});
```

You can use this same pattern to set values for $location and $window as well as others.

Answer (score 1):

There are only two possibilities:

Add `searchMatch` to the scope (as you mentioned) or

Return the `searchMatch` function:

```
function EmployeeCtrl($scope, $http, $filter, Employee) {
  return {
    searchMatch: function (haystack, needle) {
      return false;
    }
  };
 }
```

If it really must stay private, then you'll have to test the features which use it.

To get the `$filter`, you can try the following:

```
var $filter = angular.injector(['ng']).get('$filter');
```

Comment: Thanks, and how do I inject $filter?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Try with angular.injector(), which return an $injector object, which contains angular services, like $filter, $controller, ...

Answer (score 0):

To test the filter, do the following to get the target filter:

```
var ctrl, myScope, $filter;
beforeEach(inject(function(_$filter_){
    $filter = _$filter_;
}))
```

If your filter's name is "AccountTimeZone", then do this:

```
let accountTimeZoneFilter = $filter('AccountTimeZone');
```