# How do I test variables local to an Angular controller in Jasmine

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, jasmine

I have a controller with a local variable

```
function IndexCtrl($scope) {
  var pagesById = [];
  loadPages();

  // snip

  function loadPages() {
    // pagesById gets populated
  }

  // snip
}
```

I'd like to test that pagesById is correctly populated but I'm not sure how to get at it from my it(). I don't need this variable to be in the $scope, it's just an intermediate set of information, so if I can avoid adding it to $scope that would be ideal.

```
it('scope.pages should populated based on pages data.', function() {
    $httpBackend.flush();
    expect(pagesById).toEqualData(mock_page_results);
});
```

gives me

```
ReferenceError: pagesById is not defined
```

Do I have any other options besides attaching it to $scope?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In your jasmine spec, first create the controller:

```
var ctrl;

beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
  scope = $rootScope.$new();
  ctrl = $controller('myController', {
     $scope: scope
  });
}));
```

Then you can access its properties by doing `ctrl.pagesById`. Of course, rather than doing `var pagesById` you'll need to use `this.pagesById` in your controller.

Comment: that makes sense but I get TypeError: Cannot read property 'pagesById' of undefined referring to the first line in my controller where I try to read this.pagesById

Comment: `this` is probably different in the scope where you're accessing it. In the first line of your controller, do `var that = this;`, and then access `pagesById` using `that.pagesById`

Comment: heh - this is starting to look like a doctor seuss story. It worked though. I'm surprised that 'this' isn't in scope inside of a member function. Oh well Thank you. +1 vote and +1 green check!

Comment: heh. For more info on javascript scope: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/01/what-you-need-to-know-about-javascript-scope/

Comment: I don't think that this is the appropriated way to test. You want to test the resulting scope, not the controller. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14202767/testing-scope-in-angularjs-controller-with-dependency-on-filter for more info.

Comment: There are times when your controller has data that you don't want to put on the scope...

Answer (score 1):

Here is my way for testing local variables in Angular methods:

```
//------- Function for getting value of local variables

function getLocalVariable(sLocalVarName, obj, method, args){
    method = method.toString();
    let changedMethod = method.substring(0, method.lastIndexOf("}")) + ";" + "return " + sLocalVarName + "}";
    eval(' changedMethod = ' + changedMethod);

    return changedMethod.call(obj, args)
}

//----------- service

class assignStuffService {

    getAvaliableStuff(shift) {
        const params = {
            agency_id: 0 ,
            start_time: shift.data.shift.start_time,
            end_time : shift.data.shift.end_time
        };
    }
}

//----------- part of spec

it('should set values to "params" object props', () => {

            let shift = {
                data:{
                    shift:{
                        start_time:'',
                        end_time:''
                    }
                }
            };

            let params = getLocalVariable('params',
                                            assignStuffService,
                                            assignStuffService.getAvaliableStuff,
                                            shift);

            expect(params).toEqual({
                agency_id: 0 ,
                start_time: shift.data.shift.start_time,
                end_time : shift.data.shift.end_time
            });

        });
```