# Can't test method with resolved promise in angular/jasmine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, promise

I am trying to test an asynchronous method in angular. Here is code from my controller:

```
if $routeParams.mode == "new"
  # some stuff
  mySvc.GetMyStuff $routeParams.id
  .then (stuff) ->
    if stuff? and stuff.length > 1
      # do more stuff
    else 
      $scope.stuff = 'foo'
```

And my test:

```
describe "test stuff",
  $q = {}
  $scope = {}
  controller = {}
  mySvc = {}

  beforeEach inject ($controller, $rootScope, _$q_, _$routeParams_, _mySvc_)
    $q = _$q_
    $routeParams: _$routeParams_
    $scope = $rootScope.$new()
    myCtrl = $controller('MyCtrl',{
      $scope:$scope
      $routeParams: {mode: "new"}        
    })
     # create a promise to be resolved
     d = $q.defer()
     d.resolve 'foo'  # resolving with an empty array to test 'no results' condition
     spyOn(mySvc,'GetMyStuff').and.returnValue d.promise


  # later
    it "should set stuff to an 'foo'", () ->
      mySvc.GetMyStuff "id"
      $scope.$apply()
      expect($scope.stuff).toBe 'foo'   # Expected undefined to be 'foo'
```

I've also tried calling `$scope.$apply()` from the `beforeEach` block, and tried the expectation with simple strings instead of an empty array. I am expecting the data returned by the asynchronous operation to equal an empty array, which should trigger the condition that sets `$stuff` to `'foo'`. It doesn't seem that `.then` is being called with my resolved value.

EDIT: added some missing code so that example is more clear.

Comment: Check if the scope you are using in the test, is the same that you used in the controller. If not so you have to passing that scope to the controller when you inject it in the test.

Comment: check the first answer of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14202767/testing-scope-in-angularjs-controller-with-dependency-on-filter?answertab=active

Comment: I had included a brief example, but I am already doing that. I create a new scope and pass it to the controller in beforeEach. I have tested other $scope variables and the tests work as expected, it is the promise that is not resolving correctly.

Comment: you have to do $digest directly rather than $apply

Comment: You instantiate the controller, and thus call `mySvc.GetMyStuff()` **before** the method is spied. Move the spying code before the controller instantiation. And use $q.when() to create a resolved promise.

Comment: OK, that works, but I don't have to use `$q.when()`. Thanks!

Comment: You don't have to, but it's shorter and clearer than creating a defer, resolving it, and getting its promise.

Comment: @JBNizet that should be an answer.