# how to share scope in angular-ecmascript6 controller while unit-testing in SinonJS

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, ecmascript-6, sinon, chai

How can I share scope in `SinonJs`.

Here is my snippet for your reference:

```
// set up the mock
  beforeEach(() => {

    MockHomeApiService = function () {
      return {
        requestForEarlyAccess: ()=>{
          console.log("homeApiService.requestForEarlyAccess");
        } 
      }
    };

    MockTranslate = function () {
      return sinon.stub().resolves("true");
    };

  });


  // set up the angular mocks
  beforeEach(() => {
      // provide the 
      module(($provide) => {
        $provide.service('homeApiService', MockHomeApiService);
        $provide.service('$translate', MockTranslate);
      });

      // you can surround any injected dependencies with _ _ and    // the injector will throw them away, it's just to        // differentiate between variables that you might want to     // use for tests.
      inject((_$q_, _$timeout_, _homeApiService_, _$translate_) => {

          $q = _$q_
          // having $timeout is often useful for testing that
          // promises have been fulfilled
          $timeout = _$timeout_;

          // set up sinon-as-promised, otherwise it won't work!
          sinonAsPromised($q);


          homeApiService = _homeApiService_;
          $translate = _$translate_

      });
  });


// set up your controller using mocked dependencies
  beforeEach(() => {
    controller = new ApplyController(homeApiService,  userAlertsService, $log, $translate);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
inject((_$q_, _$timeout_, _homeApiService_, _$translate_, _$rootScope_) => {

      $q = _$q_
      // having $timeout is often useful for testing that
      // promises have been fulfilled
      $timeout = _$timeout_;

      // set up sinon-as-promised, otherwise it won't work!
      sinonAsPromised($q);


      homeApiService = _homeApiService_;
      $translate = _$translate_;
      $rootScope = _$rootScope_;

  });
```

and before test suite or each -

```
$scope = $rootScope.$new(true);
```

Comment: By using your way it show blank $scope instead of this I want controller scope in which all methods and vars should be available

Comment: You should pass created scope to controller; If you want to use mutated scope in your tests, you should init controller before all tests. But good way - not using scope with controller altogether, just controller as syntax and bind to this; See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14202767/testing-scope-in-angularjs-controller-with-dependency-on-filter